# Why does Firebase auth work for Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase `onAuthStateChanged()` is returning user credentials in Chrome, but not in Firefox:

[image]

What is the likely reason(s) for this?

Update: Here is the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app"),
  C = require("./constants.js");
require("firebase/auth");

firebase.initializeApp(C.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { 
    console.log('user is ' + user);
})
```

I have a lot more code in my app but after stripping everything out, this is the only code running and the issue still occurs:

[image]

Comment: Please include the [minimum code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated. Please let me know if the update is sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't include the config you're using, but just logging the result of onAuthStateChanged works for me in Firefox 50.0.2: `user is [object Object]`

Comment: @TravisChristian Right, I didn't include it because I assumed it is semi-sensitive info. It is the credentials that Firebase issues when selecting 'Add Firebase to your web app' (apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, etc.). Since it's working for you, then the issue may be local to my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you have enabled *Enhanced Tracking Protection* in your Firefox.

It needs to be disabled for the site or globally for Firebase Authentication to work. If *Enhanced Tracking Protection* is enabled, `onAuthStateChanged` is called with `null`, even when you authenticated successfully.

See Firefox documentation for configuration: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop

Comment: WOW, i've been looking for this solution for 6 months now, since the `auth` work but nothing else happened ( no error / warning nothing ) i had no idea where to start looking for solutions ... suddenly came across this question - can't believe it's finally working ! thank you !!!!

Comment: I'm confused as to why https://usaco.guide/ uses firebase auth and it works in Firefox with Enhanced Tracking Protection enabled?

Comment: Solution is to use `signInWithPopup` not `signInWithRedirect`!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using firebaseui, and could solve it with @idontknow s comment.
Use the signin with **popup** method. In firebaseui this was in `firebaseui.auth.Config` the property `signInFlow: 'popup'`